# How to alter the result of (somewhat) randomly generated circuits?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, circuit-construction, random-quantum-circuit, state-preparation

I create randomly generated circuits by iterating through a list of the gate set (in my case [$CX,SX,RZ,X$]) and adding the gate to the circuit. (In the case of the $CX$ gate we look at the topology to which qubit it connects).

Now to clarify my problem, with the help of the $SX$ gates and the $CX$ gates, we can get superposition states, which is excellent. If we use only one $SX$ gate, the simulated result will be 50% state A and 50% state B, if we use more $SX$ gates the amplitudes change a lot. If we use a sufficient amount of $SX$ gates all states will be reached with some probability.

The thing is I actually don't want this to happen. I just want to state but with different probabilities than $50/50$. for example something like $25/75$.

In general is there a way to get to this state using only one $SX$ gate?
Or can we reach the simulated result $(1/2,0,0,\sqrt{3/2})$ with only one $SX$ gate?

Comment: Just to be sure, $SX$ refers to $\sqrt{X}$? And is $RZ$ the $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ matrix or the $\begin{pmatrix}\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\frac\theta2}&0\\0&\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac\theta2}\end{pmatrix}$ matrix?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on what exactly you're asking. Are you asking if its possible to Prepare the state $|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{2}|00\rangle +\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|11\rangle$ using a single SX gate and the remaining IBM gates? I suspect not and I think I can explain why. Or are you asking in general about states like $|\psi\rangle = \sqrt{p}|00\rangle +\sqrt{1-p}|11\rangle$?